# ERROR: syntax error at or near "dec" LINE 22: ... WHEN to_char(t.work_date,'mm')=12 THEN t.work_day END.) dec

Tags: postgresql-9.5

```
select  sum(CASE WHEN to_char(t.work_date,'mm')=12 THEN t.work_day END ) dec
FROM employee t;
```

Comment: Need the help regarding the mentioned error.Kindly check.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should not be using comments except to respond to requests you get for more information or clarification. If you're not getting answers, the question is not clear or is lacking in details. Please [edit] your post to improve it rather than talking to yourself in comments.

Comment: Also, are you reading your SQL? How is `to_char` supposed to equate to `=12` when `12` is clearly an integer and not a char? And what happens to the rows that aren't equal to 12?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `dec` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) so it can't be used as an identifier. You either need to use double quotes `as "dec"` or use a different alias.

But you have another error in your code:

`to_char()` returns a character value, which can't be compare to an integer, so you need to compare it with  `'12'`

```
select sum(case when to_char(t.work_date,'mm') = '12' then t.work_day end ) as "dec"
from employee t;
```

Another way of writing this in Postgres would be to use the `filter()` clause for an aggregate. I prefer this, as it makes things more readable (at least in my opinion).

```
select sum(t.work_day) filter (where to_char(t.work_date,'mm') = '12') as "dec"
from employee t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.Anirban Sengupta (INDIA)